# How to pull a specific piece of json from an array

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I am currently using an API for steam prices and I am wondering how I can pull one specific piece of this file for example:

```
{"60's Army Jacket":"4.49","Addicted Guitarist":"3.13","Agony Yellow":"0.92","Aircraft Parts AK47":"0.89",
```

Just the prices of the item and not the market name, I am very new to this so I don't know for sure I tried a different method but I got lost and it was not working as planned so if I can be provided with resources or assistance that would be great <3.

Comment: what programming language are you using?

Comment: That's not valid JSON. Also, you should really try something yourself rather than relying on others. Maybe a tutorial like https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/JSON?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go:

```js
const data = ({"60's Army Jacket":"4.49","Addicted Guitarist":"3.13","Agony Yellow":"0.92","Aircraft Parts AK47":"0.89"});
var extractedData = [];

for (const item in data) {
   if (data.hasOwnProperty(item)) {
       extractedData.push(data[item]);
   }
}

console.log(extractedData);
```

Updated from comment:

```
const extractedValue = Object.values(data);
```

Comment: Simpler .. `extractedData = Object.values(data)`